# Student requesting to cover/reduce Mandatory Overlength Page Charge for IEEE Transaction

Tags: journals, fees

I along with my previous Professor had submitted a journal article to an IEEE Transaction. It got accepted now while I no longer work with him. Our accepted article has a page length 15 and the Mandatory Overlength Page Charge is 220$ after 8 pages. Due to funding issue, my previous Professor would only be able to pay for 3 extra pages at max. Would it be helpful if I write a mail to the concerned journal's Editor explaining my problem? Has any student got such waiver in the past?

Comment: A lot of professional societies have a policy of reducing fees for students, so I don't see any harm in asking.  You might first check whether there is any mention on the journal's web page of such a policy.  If you are working in a less wealthy country, mention that also - societies also sometimes reduce fees on that basis.

Comment: I already checked their web site. There is no such Information/Policy. However, it really does not harm writing a mail to the editor. Thank you for your response.